# I cannot figure out why fread will not populate my buffer properly. CS50 recovery

Tags: c, cs50

I've torn through this code in gdb for hours. I know that `fread` is returning the appropriate amount of bytes (`512`). Even checked the `$eax` print to confirm. Is there any chance someone may be able to give me a hint at what's wrong with my logic?

I thought that the headers may be offset from the beginning of the file, so I figured on first read going through byte by byte looking for the hex match and setting `fseek` would do the trick. No such luck. Printing match results in a `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t       BYTE;
typedef enum { false, true } boolean;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // get filenames from cml input and open file
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    char *fileName = "image";

    FILE *rawData = fopen(infile, "r");
    FILE *imgJPG  = fopen(fileName, "w");
    int match  = 0;
    int imgCnt = 0;

    // buffer to hold 512 bytes of file data - FAT file system
    BYTE *FATbuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);

    if (rawData == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error processing file. Exiting...");
        return 1;
    }

    // begin reading raw data and writing it to buffer
    while (fread(FATbuffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, rawData) == 512)
    {
        if (imgCnt == 0)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 512; c++)
            {
                if (FATbuffer[c + 0] == 0xff &&
                    FATbuffer[c + 1] == 0x8d &&
                    FATbuffer[c + 2] == 0xff)
                {
                    fseek(rawData, c, SEEK_SET);
                    imgCnt++;
                    match++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (FATbuffer[0] == 0xff &&
                FATbuffer[1] == 0x8d &&
                FATbuffer[2] == 0xff &&
                imgCnt > 0)
            {
                sprintf(fileName, "%d.jpg", imgCnt);
                fclose(imgJPG);
                imgCnt++;
            }

            if (imgJPG == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error processing file. Exiting...");
                return 3;
            }

            fwrite(FATbuffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, imgJPG);
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", match);
    // file processed, free memory
    free(FATbuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int c = 0; c < 512; c++)` and then `FATbuffer[c + 2]` within will potentially read off the end of the array, but that's probably not your issue (yet). Do you ever get into the first `if`? If you do you should probably break out of the inner loop.

Comment: I don't actually. I have the match cnt incremented in that statement just to check if the conditions cleared and they never do. Thanks for reminding me to break out of the loop.

Comment: Typo, `FATbuffer[c + 1] == 0x8d` ==> `FATbuffer[c + 1] == 0xd8`. You are looking for the wrong signature.

Comment: -_-  thank you... i've been staring at this thing for too long.

Comment: The signature you are looking for is supposed to be at the first 4 bytes of the file. That means it will not be located somewhere within a block of 512 bytes but only at the first 4 bytes of it. There is no need for that loop `for (int c = 0; c < 512; c++)`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll get rid of it.

Comment: `fclose(imgJPG);` --> Looks like that can get called more than once.   If it occurs trouble with the following `fwrite(FATbuffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, imgJPG);`.

Comment: If you're using Windows, you need to use `b` as qualifier to your 'fopen()` options — for reading and writing binary files.  On Unix-based systems, that does no harm but also doesn't do any particular good.

Comment: regarding: `fseek(rawData, c, SEEK_SET);`   there are several lines in the 'image" file, at the beginning, that are not part of any image,  so stepping back to the beginning of the file is an error

Comment: regarding: FILE *imgJPG  = fopen(fileName, "w");`  this will need to be done, many times, once for each newly found  image in the input file.  Also, each output file needs to have a unique  3 digit number in the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should test if a command line argument is available (after handling options, code you probably removed for posting).
- files must be open in binary mode to avoid potential end of translation.
- you should delay opening `imgJPG` until you have found the JPG header.
- there is no need to allocate `FATbuffer`, defining a 512 byte array with automatic storage is fine.
- you scan for the JPG signature one block at a time, but you might miss the signature if it spans a 512 byte boundary and you access 2 bytes beyond the end of the `FATbuffer` array when `c` is greater than 509.
- `fseek(rawData, c, SEEK_SET);` set the file position at the offset from the beginning of the array, not from the beginning of the file.
- `sprintf(fileName, "%d.jpg", imgCnt);` attempts to overwrite a string constant. This has undefined behavior. You probably meant this:

  ```
    char fileName[64];
    snprintf(fileName, sizeof fileName, "image%d.jpg", imgCnt);
    FILE *imgJPG = fopen(fileName, "wb");
  ```

Here is a modified version that can extract JPG files embedded anywhere in a data stream:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // get filenames from cml input and open file
    if (optind >= argc)
        return 1;
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    FILE *rawData = fopen(infile, "rb");  // open the disk image
    char fileName[64];
    FILE *imgJPG = NULL;
    int imgCnt = 0;

    // buffer to hold 512 bytes of file data - FAT file system
    // add an extra 2 bytes to match signature across sector boundaries
    uint8_t FATbuffer[514];

    // begin reading raw data into buffer
    int pos = 2;
    while (fread(FATbuffer + 2, 1, 512, rawData) == 512) {
        for (int c = pos; c < 512; c++) {
            if (FATbuffer[c + 0] == 0xff &&
                FATbuffer[c + 1] == 0x8d &&
                FATbuffer[c + 2] == 0xff) {
                // found signature: skip to a new file
                if (imgJPG) {
                    // write the end of the current image
                    fwrite(FATbuffer + pos, c - pos, 1, imgJPG);
                    fclose(imgJPG);
                }
                pos = c;
                imgCnt++;
                snprintf(fileName, sizeof fileName, "image%d.jpg", imgCnt);
                imgJPG = fopen(fileName, "wb");
                if (imgJPG == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create file %s: %s\n",
                            fileName, strerror(errno));
                    return 3;
                }
            }
        }
        if (imgJPG) {
            // write end of block to current image
            fwrite(FATbuffer + pos, 512 - pos, 1, imgJPG);
        }
        // copy the last 2 bytes to test for signature overlapping blocks
        FATbuffer[0] = FATbuffer[512];
        FATbuffer[1] = FATbuffer[513];
        // uncopied file data starts a 0 now.
        pos = 0;
    }
    if (imgJPG) {
        // write last 2 bytes to current image
        fwrite(FATbuffer, 2, 1, imgJPG);
        fclose(imgJPG);
    }
    printf("%d\n", imgCnt != 0);
    printf("%d images extracted\n", imgCnt);
    return 0;
}
```

If you can assume the signature to be at the start of a sector, the code can be simplified:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // get filenames from cml input and open file
    if (optind >= argc)
        return 1;
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    FILE *rawData = fopen(infile, "rb");  // open the disk image
    char fileName[64];
    FILE *imgJPG = NULL;
    int imgCnt = 0;

    // buffer to hold 512 bytes of file data - FAT file system
    uint8_t FATbuffer[512];

    // begin reading raw data into buffer
    while (fread(FATbuffer, 1, 512, rawData) == 512) {
        if (FATbuffer[c + 0] == 0xff &&
            FATbuffer[c + 1] == 0x8d &&
            FATbuffer[c + 2] == 0xff) {
            // found signature: skip to a new file
            if (imgJPG) {
                fclose(imgJPG);
            }
            imgCnt++;
            snprintf(fileName, sizeof fileName, "image%d.jpg", imgCnt);
            imgJPG = fopen(fileName, "wb");
            if (imgJPG == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create file %s: %s\n",
                        fileName, strerror(errno));
                return 3;
            }
        }
        if (imgJPG) {
            // write end of block to current image
            fwrite(FATbuffer, 512, 1, imgJPG);
        }
    }
    if (imgJPG) {
        fclose(imgJPG);
    }
    printf("%d\n", imgCnt != 0);
    printf("%d images extracted\n", imgCnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thaaaaank you for taking the time to look through that. I really appreciate it.

Comment: First time using stack. Really should have read the instructions. Thank you!!!